# Use a specific Line of a csv File

Tags: powershell

I hope that someone can give me a little help.

I want to search a csv file for an entry in column F. The entries in this line should be able to then be processed further.

How can this be implemented?

Thanks in advance
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cmdlet for importing CSV data is `Import-Csv` (how surprising). From there you can filter accordingly:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv | Where-Object { $_.F -eq 'bar' }
```

or select just the data from a single column:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv | Select-Object -Expand F
```

or do both (with aliases now):

```
Import-Csv foo.csv | ? { $_.F -eq 'bar' } | select -exp F
```

Further processing can then be done with `ForEach-Object` or `%` (its alias):

```
... | % {
  <# do stuff with $_ here #>
}
```

Comment: Tank you for the quick response!!

Answer (score 0):

Just prototype, you need to replace `<anchors>` with what you need:

```
Import-Csv YourFile.csv | 
    where { $_.F <operator> <value> } | 
    foreach {
        <process $_ with column names attached as it's properties>
    }
```